# Executing Azure SQL DML statements from Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to run the azure sql DML statements (update or delete) from Azure machine learning studio. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no. There is no odbc driver in the container.

If you provide some more details about what you want to delete maybe I can offer a workaround.

But to update a Db... You could use execute python to send an event to an event hub(in a service bus). Then connect to that event hub via stream analytics. There you can set the azure SQL Db as an output port to update your row.

Let me know if you need more details about any step.

Comment: This is my requirement. Please check the below link, http://stackoverflow.com/q/37497533/4046334